# Correct use of "have been"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-constructions, past-continuous

Would it be correct to say
"Since I have been reading this book, I have been learning so much"

or

"Since I have been reading this book, I have learned so much"

Comment: Hello Tom, and welcome to ELL! On this site, we require users to show they've already made a little effort to answer the question themselves, and to tell us what they already know about the grammar involved. Please use the small "Edit" button to tell us what you already know about the difference between present perfect continuous and present perfect in this context, what you have already found online, and so on -- anything that will help us answer your question without having to guess what you already know. Thanks!

Comment: Also, have a look at ["How to ask a good question"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, I would say a good way to phrase that if you must include "have been" would be your second example. However, the following is a more common way to communicate the same meaning:

> Since I began reading this book, I have learned so much.